# Atom CSS preview color package

Tags: package, atom-editor

I need to know the name of the package which provide the circle with a preview of the CSS color value in Atom,
can any one help

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're referring to [Pigments](https://atom.io/packages/pigments).

The default is to highlight the color declaration with the color. The option to display color as a dot at the end of the line is called "Marker Type" (or, `pigments.markerType`).

See the [doc page](https://atom.io/packages/pigments) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If I may also add to this:

There is a newer package called [Chromo](https://atom.io/packages/chromo-color-previews) available for atom.

Chromo will put color preview pills in the gutter for css colors similar to what you described and supports hex, rgb, rgba, and ansi color values at the moment.